# container Div is not 100% height in different computer screen?

Tags: html, css

i have a page consist of html code and css all css are working with fine inside my laptop where i'm developing my page but my problem now is that when i try to run it in another computer(desktop computer) which is much bigger screen the width is ok but the height is not 100% height of the screen. as you can see in the picture there's a border color orange, that is my container div, now below that orange border there's a space and that's my problem.

[image]

**CSS**

```
body{
background-color: #e9e8e8;
font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

**this is the image**

```
#slider{
width: 80%;
height: 550px;
margin: 19.5px auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
overflow: hidden;
}
.items{
max-height: 100%;
height: 550px;
min-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.items img{
 width:100%;
 height:550px;
}
```

**Footer**

```
.footer{
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
box-shadow: 0 8px 30px -6px black;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #2ebf16, #217812);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2ebf16), to(#217812));
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2ebf16, #217812);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#2ebf16', EndColorStr='#217812');
}
```

Comment: because of this? `height: 550px;`

Comment: yeah that's the height of my slider..so, what should i do?

Comment: `height:100vh` change the value of the body slider to this value, the meaning of this is to set the height of an element 100% based on the view port. So the first thing you do is to set the slider height to `100vh` and set your item heights to inherit :)

Comment: so what should the value of the items?

Comment: .items{
height: inherit; } the other properties leave it as is just change the height

Comment: i already tried your code it worked, but now the image stay at the same size but the height is 100vh so i get a black colot below my .items

Comment: did you inspect element in browser what is the source of this black color? i think this is of your shadow effects, if you want them to be visible again try to adjust the height to 90vh, to give space for margins and box shadows

Comment: i think it occur because my image is fixed to 550px so when i change it to 100vh and change the .items height to inherit it gives me a black color below the image

Comment: yes because it was set to 100% leaving no space for other css properties like border shadows. To solve it faster can you create a fiddle for this? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what do ineed to put in jsfiddle.css only?

Comment: you can actually add all the necessary widgets to run your site there, so we can replicate it easily

Comment: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/0ogdLhj8/

Comment: the images didnt load :)

Comment: yeah..i don't know its not loading..

Comment: upload first your images to image uploading site like imgur, then the src path to point to the absolute URL

Comment: na update ko na yung fiddle, please check and tell me whats wrong in there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114298/trojan

Comment: i try this path img src="imgur.com/image.png" is that right? it uploading now

Comment: hindi ako makapagreply.

Comment: i'm alredy login in stackexchage but still can't chat with you

Comment: can we chat in gmail?

Comment: ok give me your email

Comment: i'll delete it as soon as you get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's occurs because the property height isn't based on ViewPort.

You can use a [viewport relative lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) or use some approaches to Viewport height.

Examples approaches:

- You can define 100% at all height elements;
- Use position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0;

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the space below you orange border you need to specify a viewport height for that div. like so

```
div.container {
 height: 100vh; // This does the trick
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

You can read more about `vh` here, https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: should i change my.container-fluid to di.container?

Comment: i tried your code and now its 100% of the screen but there's again a problem my footer stays on the same area.its not go down

Comment: You need to make the footer an absolute value

Comment: add `#footer { postion: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100% }` and your order css property

Comment: it worked but the footer width is not 100%..theres a space on the right

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}
```

I see you're using container-fluid class, so you're probably using bootstrap, which also could be over-riding something.

Comment: Well, not very recommended, but try adding height: 100% !important;

Comment: i tried to put height: 100vh; and it worked and its now 100% of the screen but the problem is that the footer stays on the same area.it doesn't go down